# JQuery. Facing problems with click events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was writing code for image flip game in jquery but I am facing some problems with the click events on image in the beginning. The problems are when I click one image and click again the same image it works fine but if I click one image, the image src attribute is added to the img tag and then if I click any other image the src attribute is not added to that one for the first click because the clickCounter has the value 1 then. I employed my own logic (clickCounter). I am new to jquery. You may suggest a better way to do this. Thanks in advance.
Here is my code.

```
    <style>
        #main{
            height: 500px;
            border: 1px solid blue;
            margin: auto;
        }
        .myimg{
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            background: lightblue;
            background-position: center center;
            margin: 10px;
            float: left;
            border-radius: 20px;
        }
    </style>

<body>
    <div id="main">

    </div>
    <button id="add">Add</button>

    <script src="jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
    <script>
        var clickCounter = 0;
        $('#add').click(function(){
            addElements(44);
            $('#add').attr('disabled', 'true');
        });
        function addElements(times){
            var main = $('#main');
            for(j = 1; j <= times; j++){
                var i = document.createElement('img');
                var img = $(i);
                img.click(function(){
                    // $(this).css('background', 'url(back.png)');
                    var myImage = $(this);
                    if(clickCounter == 0){
                        myImage.attr('src', 'back.png');
                        myImage.attr('width', '100');
                        myImage.attr('height', '100');
                        clickCounter = 1;
                    }else{
                        myImage.removeAttr('src');
                        clickCounter = 0;
                    }
                    //alert(clickCounter);
                });
                img.addClass('myimg');
                main.append(img);   
            }       
        }

    </script>
</body>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nu973q8q/)

Comment: posting this code in an interactive, testable [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) and giving us a link to it would help us answer the question more quickly

Comment: What is the purpose of `clickCounter`? What exactly do you want to happen on the click events?

Comment: You should use `.toggle() ` to fix second click, checks some examples [here](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the shared variable `clickCounter` which is shared between all the elements.

In this case since you have dynamic elements, you could use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) and then use the current `src` value of the `img` to set the new one like

```
$('#add').click(function () {
    addElements(44);
    $('#add').prop('disabled', true);
});

$('#main').on('click', '.myimg', function () {
    $(this).attr('src', function (i, src) {
        return src == 'back.png' ? '' : 'back.png';
    }).height(100).width(100);
})

function addElements(times) {
    var $main = $('#main');
    for (j = 1; j <= times; j++) {
        $('<img />', {
            'class': 'myimg'
        }).appendTo($main)
    }
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2Lhyqbpp/)

Comment: Bundles of Thanks. Good

Answer (score 1):

Instead of counter, check for 'src' attribute as shown below,

```js
        $('#add').click(function(){
            addElements(44);
            $('#add').attr('disabled', 'true');
        });
        function addElements(times){
            var main = $('#main');
            for(j = 1; j <= times; j++){
                var i = document.createElement('img');
                var img = $(i);
                img.click(function(){
                    // $(this).css('background', 'url(back.png)');
                    var myImage = $(this);
                  var attr = $(this).attr('src');
                    if(typeof attr == typeof undefined){
                        myImage.attr('src', 'back.png');
                        myImage.attr('width', '100');
                        myImage.attr('height', '100');                          
                    }else{
                        myImage.removeAttr('src');
                        
                    }
                    //alert(clickCounter);
                });
                img.addClass('myimg');
                main.append(img);   
            }       
        }
```

```css
#main{
            height: 500px;
            border: 1px solid blue;
            margin: auto;
        }
        .myimg{
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            background: lightblue;
            background-position: center center;
            margin: 10px;
            float: left;
            border-radius: 20px;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">

    </div>
    <button id="add">Add</button>
```

Comment: @Arun P Johny What logic should be used to take one image source two times only randomly but not more than two times of the same image.